# tzeddaka from stocks/401K

Tags: tzedakah-charity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ma’aser kesafim on capital appreciation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4084/maaser-kesafim-on-capital-appreciation)

how are we supposed to give maaser from our investments? should we give it only when we take the money out? she we give it yearly on the condition that there is a gain? this is very confusing to me.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know it doesn't matter. You just have to give maaser from all money gains one time before you use that money.

Comment: source?????????